# How can I tell if an React-Bootstrap component has finished rendering?

Tags: reactjs, twitter-bootstrap, performance, optimization, react-bootstrap

I have a React Bootstrap accordion with a lot of data in it that takes a couple seconds to load and doesn't work properly if you try to expand it before that. I would like to hide/overlay the accordion until the render is finished.

To be clear: this is not a question of waiting on the server for the data to load - it's all available on the client, there's just a lot to render. I can't find anything in the React docs about how to handle this case.

I tried using Accordion onLoad event to set a loading flag in component state. However, Bootstrap never seems to actually trigger it and I can't find any other event that I would expect to work.

Update: I am using functional components by the way.

Comment: provide some code you already tried

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I figured it out, set the loading flag in an empty-array useEffect for the component and it'll trigger when the rendering is complete. Very simple solution, just not as immediately intuitive with functional components.

```
const [accordionRendering, setAccordionRendering] = React.useState(true);
...
    
React.useEffect(() => setAccordionRendering(false), [])
...

return <React.Fragment>
    <Spinner animation="border" className={accordionRendering ? '' : 'd-none'}/>
    <Accordion activeKey={activeKey} onSelect={onAccordionChanged} className={accordionRendering ? 'invisible' : ''}>
...
```